# How does Spring read x-www-form-urlencoded content Type?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, x-www-form-urlencoded

I was trying to create a custom HTTP Servlet Request Wrapper to read HTTP Servlet Request multiple times. It worked fine with JSON but kept failing when the content type was *x-www-form-urlencoded*.
I was able to read it only once but was unable to convert it to Params. I am using *@RequestParam* to read the values.
Can anyone please explain how Spring reads the 'x-www-form-urlencoded' type request and how it is different from normal JSON type.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring doesn't. That functionality is built into the Servlet API.

Comment: The built in Servlet API will use the getParameterMap() method to read the params. I tried overriding that in the custom HTTP Servlet Request but it still wasn't being read the 2nd time in the controller